# Why does classList.key == true not execute my if statement?

Tags: javascript

Using this code to create a simple math quiz. I have button's that are set string values for both the button's text and . The issue I'm currently, is having the setter properly the button's class value after evaluating it's key value.

Inside my setStatusClass. I used if's to check the object's key values for correct. I used debugger to see if the values were even being checked. And, they are. But, I'm understand the blocks aren't being ran.

```js
// This document, when the start button is clicked, shows questions, & starts the timer
var startButton = document.getElementById("start-btn");
var questionContainerEl = document.getElementById("question-container");
var startScreen = document.getElementById("start-screen");
var questionTitle = document.getElementById("question");
var choiceButtons = document.getElementById("choice-buttons");
//var buttonVal = 0;
var score = 0;
var shuffleQuestions, currentQindex;
var i = 0;

//Object Container to hold questions and answers
const questions = [{
    question: "What is 2 + 2?",
    answers: [
        {text: "4", correct: "true"},
        {text: "2", correct: "false"},
        {text: "3", correct: "false"},
        {text: "5", correct: "false"}
        ]
},
{
    question: "What is 4*4?",
    answers: [{text: '8', correct: "false"},
        {text: '16',correct: "true"},
        {text: '2', correct: "false"},
        {text: '6', correct: "false"},
        ]
},
{
    question: "Solve for x. y = 3x - 6",
    answers: [{text: '6', correct: "false"},
    {text: '3', correct: "false"},
    {text: '2', correct: "true"},
    {text: "idk", correct: "false"}]
}]; 

startButton.addEventListener('click',startGame);
//Start game function shows Question Cont. Shuffles Questions on an Arr.
function startGame() {
    startScreen.classList.add('hide');
    shuffleQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5);
    currentQindex = 0;
    questionContainerEl.classList.remove('hide');
    setNextQuestion();
}  
//Erases question and finds next one on Arr.
function setNextQuestion() {
    resetState();
    showQuestion(shuffleQuestions[currentQindex]);
}
//Shows question as well as answers.
function showQuestion(questions){
    questionTitle.innerText = questions.question;
    var ansLength = Object.keys(questions.answers).length;
    var ans;
    for(i = 0; i < ansLength; i++) {
        //When the answer button is selected questions goes to next object element
        ans = questions.answers[i];
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerText = ans.text;
        button.classList.add('btn');
        
        if(ans.correct === "true") {
            button.correct = ans.correct;
            
        } 
        button.addEventListener("click", selectAnswer);
        choiceButtons.appendChild(button);
    }
}
//removes buttons from choices.
function resetState() {
    while(choiceButtons.firstChild) {
        choiceButtons.removeChild(choiceButtons.firstChild);
    }
}
function selectAnswer(e) {
    //setStatusClass(document.body, isCorrect);
    var ar = Array.from(choiceButtons.children);
    for (buttons of ar) {
        var selectedButton = e.target;
        var isCorrect = selectedButton.dataset.correct;
        setStatusClass(buttons, isCorrect);
    }
}
function setStatusClass(element) {
    clearStatusClass(element);
    if (element.classList.correct == "true") {
        element.classList.add("right");
    } 
    if (element.classList.correct == "false") {
        element.classList.add("incorrect");
    }
}
function clearStatusClass(element){
    element.classList.remove("right");
    element.classList.remove("incorrect");
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:  "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #b3d7ff;
}
.start-screen {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.start-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;

}
.btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,auto);
}
.btn {
    border: black;
    background-color: #b3d7ff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: dashed;
    margin: 5px;
}
.btn.right {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color:black
}
.btn.incorrect {
    background-color: red;
    color:black;
}
.btn:hover{
    border-color: black;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}
.scores {
    float:left;
    align-self: flex-start; 
    position: absolute;
}
.timer {
    float:left;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
.container {
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px; 
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
#question {
    width: 700px;
    max-width: 80%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    margin-right: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge"  />
    <title>The Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Assets/css/style.css" type = "text/css" media= "screen">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="scores"><a href="highscores.html">View Highscores</a></div>

    <div class="timer">Time: <span id="time">0</span></div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="start-screen" class="start">
            <h1>The Quiz</h1>
            <p>
                This quiz is on a timer. Please do your best to complete it before the timer runs out.
                Keep in mind that wrong answers will penalize you.
            </p>
            <button id="start-btn" class = "start-btn btn?">Start the Quiz</button> 
        </div>

            <div id= "question-container" class= "hide">
                <div id="question">Question</div>
                <div id="choice-buttons" class= "btn-grid">
                    <button class= "btn hover">Answer 1</button>
                    <button class= "btn hover">Answer 2</button>
                    <button class= "btn hover">Answer 3</button>
                    <button class= "btn hover">Answer 4</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div id="final-screen" class= "hide">
            <h2>You're finished</h2>
            <p>Your final score is<span id="final-score"></span>.</p>
            <p>
                Enter intials: <input type="text" id="initals" max="3" />
                <button id="submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script defer src="./Assets/js/logic.js"></script>
    <script defer src="./Assets/js/questions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to tell if a class is in an element's class list is with the `.includes()` method.

```
function setStatusClass(element) {
    clearStatusClass(element);
    if (element.classList.includes("correct")) {
        element.classList.add("right");
    } else {
        element.classList.add("incorrect");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the "incorrect is not a function" error when I try this. Is there a work around you would suggest?

Comment: Fixed it. I think initially includes was checking the button as a button. &, in order for the includes to work properly I have to pass correct as a parameter. Then, added a typeof in the conditional to check if it was a string. 

Now if only I could get selectAnswer function to properly set the keys to each individual button.